# Check if item in arrays containing numbers

Tags: python, arrays

**Input**: I have this multiple array:

```
arr = [array(['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG'],dtype=object),array(['AL', 'YOUM14', 'HADCO'],dtype=object)]
```

**Code1**: To loop thru item in arr

```
for item in arr:
    print(item)
```

**Output code1**:

```
['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG']
['AL', 'YOUM14', 'HADCO']
```

**Code2**:  To check if item in array containing numbers

```
import numpy as np
arr1=['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG']

for a in arr1:  
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10):
        sum += a.count(str(i))
    print(sum)
```

**Ouput code2**:

```
0
0
2
```

**Question**: How to use code2 to loop thru output in code1 to get following output:

```
['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG']  -> 0 0 2
['AL', 'YOUM14', 'HADCO'] -> 0 2 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: use nested for loops,`for item in arr:` `for a in item:` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might helps :)

```
import numpy as np
arr = [np.array(['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG'],dtype=object),np.array(['AL', 'YOUM14', 'HADCO'],dtype=object)]

arr1=['ABU', 'KASS', '10KG']


for arr1 in arr:
    sum_list = []
    for a in arr1:  
        sum = 0
        for i in range(10):
            sum += a.count(str(i))
        sum_list.append(sum)
    print(arr1,"->",sum_list)
```

Comment: VJAYSLN, please let me have more questions.
After running the code above, instead of printing everything, can we print 1 thing only which is the unique item containing more numbers than other items.

Example: 
 ['ABU', '222KASS', '10KG'] ->  0,3,2
Kindly let me know how to print "222KASS" only as it contains more numbers than any other items

Comment: @intelligence, you can rewrite your program, such that find total of sum..And then find maximum total among these sum and print.

Comment: @intelligence, If this helpful, pl upvote this. So that, one can easily find solutions.

Answer (score 0):

... are you posting your programming homework?

```
for a in arr:  
    for b in a:  
        sum = 0
        for i in range(10):
            sum += b.count(str(i))
        print(sum)
```